# how to sql function return value insert into a specific table column.in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a sql function that return age when i send birthdate as parameter.this is given below:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_calculateAge] (@dob date)
  RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @age int

SET @age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dob, GETDATE()) -
            CASE
             WHEN (MONTH(@dob) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR
                  (MONTH(@dob) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@dob) > DAY(GETDATE()))
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END
RETURN @age

END
```

now i want to insert it into a specific table column.i try below code.it show invalid column name.

```
    insert into [Ehealth].[dbo].[PatientTable]([Age]) values ([dbo].fn_calculateAge([Birth date]))
```

but column name is right.

so how can i call this function in asp.net and insert return value in a specific column.

If someone could help me I would be highly appreciated!!! Thanks.

Comment: Read ADO.NET, SQLConnecto, SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: You create a sql command and set command text with parameters or use an extension method in linq for sql for retrieve tha value

Comment: You cannot use that insert statement unless [Birth Date] is a variable. Otherwise use a `insert into ...select ` statement

Comment: @mybirthname thanks for your advice.

Comment: @H.Herzl this procedure helps me .thanks

Comment: @CynicalSection update statement works well . thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need an update statement to update each existing row to set the Age column for the date given in the birthdate column. It would be something like this;

```
UPDATE [Ehealth].[dbo].[PatientTable] SET [Age] = [dbo].fn_calculateAge([Birth date])
```

This will work if [Birth date] is the name of the column containing the values you would like to use as the argument for [dbo].fn_calculateAge.